# Optimal object to return from this method asp.net csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, webusercontrol

Having a checkedboxlist databound with encrypted listitem value, i had written a method to return a array holding respective checked items on postback.
Signature of which would be similar to below

`private Array GetCheckedItems(CheckBoxList ctrlChkbox)
{
//decrypt and push to array
}`

Is this a optimal object to return. I will be accessing the array items again to be individually pushed into DataBase.( I will also be binding the same data with a gridview again to show the records. It's like single page form with a gridview to show records)
 Which objects might get me benefits and performance than arrays. key based would be nice i feel. Advice me on this please,
Regards,
Deeptechtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance around collections is quite difficult to answer.

`Array` "simple" provides good performances if items count is known (like it seems for you, if the checked item list is accessible from UI), and if you access it quite straight-forwardly.

Little informations about `List<T>`, as you said you would put it back into a gridview.
You should try to be concerned (depending on element's number, always) about "boxing/unboxing" informations.
I think that would be your main issue. 
Extracting value to push it into database or to gridview may be two different uses for your datas.

if "boxing/unboxing" match your concern more than collecting elements, a linkedList could be a way to insert/read it one after the other.
In case of many elements (don't know which number), `addRange()` in `List<T>` is also to consider

Always many ways to do it, hard to

Comment: Due to the fact i also depend on binding to grid, you mean to say strongly typed list's suffice my purpose? My items number are predetermined not exceeding 10. So shall i go `array's` way

Comment: Binding to grid would make think about strong-typed datas. But grid and list don't have same ones. Finally only 10 elements, predetermined, go `Array` yes, that's more simple. Don't care too much about performance for 10 elements